# Cocos2D Sprite Animation - Sprite Only Sliding Across Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I am having some trouble getting the sprite to do a walking animation. Currently, it is only displaying the first frame of the animation and is "sliding" across the screen. I have tried a few different things but with no success and am in need of some help to find out where the issue is.

Below is the header file for the sprite class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "mainGameLayer.h"

@class MainGameLayer, Waypoint, Tower;

@interface Unit : CCSprite {
    CGPoint myPosition;
    int maxHP;
    int currentHP;
    float walkingSpeed;
    Waypoint *destinationWaypoint;
    BOOL active;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MainGameLayer *theGame;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *mySprite;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCAction *walkAction;

@property (nonatomic, assign) float centerToSides;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float centerToBottom;

+(id) nodeWithTheGame: (MainGameLayer *)_game;
-(id) initWithTheGame: (MainGameLayer *)_game;
-(void) doActivate;
-(void) getRemoved;

@end
```

Sprite class implementation file:

```
#import "Unit.h"
#import "Tower.h"
#import "Waypoint.h"

#define HEALTH_BAR_WIDTH 20
#define HEALTH_BAR_ORIGIN -10

@implementation Unit

@synthesize theGame;
@synthesize mySprite;

+(id) nodeWithTheGame:(MainGameLayer *)_game
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithTheGame:_game];
}

// BELOW IS THE ORIGINAL INIT FUNCTION, UNMODIFIED, AND IN WORKING CONDITION
-(id) initWithTheGame:(MainGameLayer *)_game
{
    if ((self=[super init])) {

        CCArray *walkFrames = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hero_walk_%02d.png", i]];
            [walkFrames addObject:frame];
        }
        CCAnimation *walkAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:[walkFrames getNSArray] delay:1.0/12.0];

        theGame = _game;
        maxHP = 40;
        currentHP = maxHP;

        active = FALSE;

        walkingSpeed = 0.5;

        Waypoint * waypoint = (Waypoint *)[theGame.waypoints objectAtIndex:([theGame.waypoints count]-1)];

        destinationWaypoint = waypoint.nextWaypoint;

        CGPoint pos = waypoint.myPosition;
        myPosition = pos;

        self.mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"hero_walk_00.png"];
        self.mySprite.position = pos;
        [self addChild:mySprite];

        mySprite.flipX = 180;

        self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnimation]];

        [theGame addChild:self];

        [self scheduleUpdate];

    }

    return self;
}

-(void) doActivate
{
    active = TRUE;
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self runAction: self.walkAction];
}

-(void)  update:(ccTime)dt
{
    if(!active)return;

    if([theGame circle:myPosition withRadius:1 collisionWithCircle:destinationWaypoint.myPosition
 collisionCircleRadius:1])
    {
        if(destinationWaypoint.nextWaypoint)
        {
            destinationWaypoint = destinationWaypoint.nextWaypoint;
        }else
        {
            //Reached the end of the road. Damage the player
            [theGame getHpDamage];
            [self getRemoved];
        }
    }

    CGPoint targetPoint = destinationWaypoint.myPosition;
    float movementSpeed = walkingSpeed;

    CGPoint normalized = ccpNormalize(ccp(targetPoint.x-myPosition.x,targetPoint.y-myPosition.y));
    mySprite.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(normalized.y,-normalized.x));

    myPosition = ccp(myPosition.x+normalized.x * movementSpeed,
                     myPosition.y+normalized.y * movementSpeed);

    [mySprite setPosition:myPosition];
}

-(void) getRemoved
{
    [self.parent removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
    [theGame.units removeObject: self];

    // Notify the game that we killed an enemy so we can check if we can send another wave
    [theGame enemyGotKilled];
}

-(void) draw
{
    ccDrawSolidRect(ccp(myPosition.x + HEALTH_BAR_ORIGIN, myPosition.y + 16), ccp(myPosition.x + HEALTH_BAR_ORIGIN + HEALTH_BAR_WIDTH, myPosition.y + 14), ccc4f(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0));

    ccDrawSolidRect(ccp(myPosition.x + HEALTH_BAR_ORIGIN, myPosition.y + 16), ccp(myPosition.x + HEALTH_BAR_ORIGIN + (float)(currentHP * HEALTH_BAR_WIDTH)/maxHP, myPosition.y + 14), ccc4f(0, 1.0, 0, 1.0));
}



@end
```

Here is the main game header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface MainGameLayer : CCLayer {
}

+ (CCScene *) scene;
- (BOOL) circle:(CGPoint)circlePoint withRadius:(float)radius collisionWithCircle:(CGPoint)circlePointTwo collisionCircleRadius:(float)radiusTwo;
void ccFillPoly (CGPoint *poli, int points, BOOL closePolygon);
- (void) enemyGotKilled;
- (void) getHpDamage;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *towers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *waypoints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *units;

@end
```

And finally the main game implementation file:

```
#import "MainGameLayer.h"
#import "Tower.h"
#import "Waypoint.h"
#import "Unit.h"


@implementation MainGameLayer

@synthesize towers;
@synthesize waypoints;
@synthesize units;

+ (CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    MainGameLayer *layer = [MainGameLayer node];

    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // Initialize
        self.isTouchEnabled = TRUE;
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        // Setting the background (Map)
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"layout.png"];
        [self addChild: background];
        [background setPosition: ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2)];

        [self addWaypoints];

        // In Game Buttons / Menu
        CCMenuItem *sampleButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"sample.jpg" selectedImage:@"sample.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(samplePurchased:)];

        CCMenu *PurchaseUI = [CCMenu menuWithItems:sampleButton, nil];
        [PurchaseUI setScale:0.5];
        [PurchaseUI setPosition:ccp(63, 51)];
        [PurchaseUI alignItemsHorizontally];
        PurchaseUI.isTouchEnabled = TRUE;
        [self addChild: PurchaseUI];

        // Set up the sprite sheets (Currently in testing)
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"pd_sprites.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"pd_sprites.pvr.ccz"];
        [self addChild: spriteSheet];
    }

    return self;

}

-(BOOL) canBuyTower
{
    return YES;
}

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
        CCLOG(@"X: %f Y: %f", location.x, location.y);

        if ([self canBuyTower]) {
            // Spend the gold later
            Tower *tower = [Tower nodeWithTheGame:self location: location];
            [towers addObject: tower];
        }
    }
}

-(void) addWaypoints
{
    waypoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Waypoint * waypoint1 = [Waypoint nodeWithTheGame:self location:ccp(-25,360)];
    [waypoints addObject:waypoint1];

    Waypoint * waypoint2 = [Waypoint nodeWithTheGame:self location:ccp(73,360)];
    [waypoints addObject:waypoint2];
    waypoint2.nextWaypoint =waypoint1;

    Waypoint * waypoint3 = [Waypoint nodeWithTheGame:self location:ccp(467,360)];
    [waypoints addObject:waypoint3];
    waypoint3.nextWaypoint =waypoint2;

    Waypoint * waypoint4 = [Waypoint nodeWithTheGame:self location:ccp(905,360)];
    [waypoints addObject:waypoint4];
    waypoint4.nextWaypoint =waypoint3;

    Waypoint * waypoint5 = [Waypoint nodeWithTheGame:self location:ccp(1050,360)];
    [waypoints addObject:waypoint5];
    waypoint5.nextWaypoint =waypoint4;
}

-(BOOL) circle:(CGPoint)circlePoint withRadius:(float)radius collisionWithCircle:(CGPoint)circlePointTwo collisionCircleRadius:(float)radiusTwo
{
    float xdif = circlePoint.x - circlePointTwo.x;
    float ydif = circlePoint.y - circlePointTwo.y;

    float distance = sqrt(xdif*xdif + ydif*ydif);

    if (distance <= radius + radiusTwo) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

-(void) samplePurchased: (id)sender
{
    Unit *unit = [Unit nodeWithTheGame: self];
    [units addObject: unit];
    [unit schedule:@selector(doActivate)];
}

@end
```

Comment: [mySprite runAction:walkAction]  ?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this selector runs every frame:

```
-(void) doActivate
{
    active = TRUE;
    [self stopAllActions];
    [self runAction: self.walkAction];
}
```

So every frame it stops all actions, and runs a new walk action. Next frame walk action is stopped, then restarted. Rinse and repeat.

Since the walk anim is starting over every frame, it will never have any chance of advancing to the next frame.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a beginner question, but why does 'doActivate' run every frame? I could be wrong, but I believe I coded it to call 'doActivate' once for each unit once the player hits the button to buy the unit. I changed it so that I removed the 'stopallactions' line and instead put in a flag saying if it is not already doing the run action, then run it; this has produced the same result where my sprite is sliding.

Comment: [unit schedule:@selector(doActivate)]; <== schedules the selector to be called every frame

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for clearing that up. I didn't realize it was scheduling it to call every frame. I always thought that it was just to call that particular function once. I've replaced it so that I am only calling the function once now, but it seems I still have the same problem. Any ideas as to what else may be causing this to happen? Again, thank you for the help so far!